# How can I prevent duplication of the content in itemtamplate for the alternating template in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater, itemtemplate, code-duplication

Is there a way to prevent duplication ot an itemtemplate content which will just appear with a different css class for the alternating template block?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCommentHistory" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comment").ToString() %>' 
          Class="itemTemplate"/>
     </ItemTemplate>

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comment").ToString() %>' 
          Class="alternatingTtemTemplate"/>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:-)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' CssClass='<%# Container.ItemIndex%2==0?"itemTemplate":"alternatingTtemTemplate" %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

I never make use of the `AlternatingItemTemplate`. I don't like having to duplicate my code for the purpose of having an alternating item, and I think that if the code is that different that it cannot be classed as a duplicate, then you shouldn't be using a `Repeater` control anyway.

Therefore I always just use the `ItemTemplate`, and make any changes I need to in the `ItemDataBound` event.

To determine whether the item is a normal, or alternating item, I would do something like:

```
if ((e.Item.ItemIndex+1 % 2)=0){
   //Alternating code here..
}
```

In your case the only difference is a change to the `Label` `CssClass`, so I would do something like:

```
if ((e.Item.ItemIndex+1 % 2)=0){
   Label lblComment = e.Item.FindControl("lblComment");
   lblComment.CssClass = "alternatingTtemTemplate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really duplication as such, don't worry about it. You are implementing this pretty much as intended.

The only other option I can think of would be to use the itemtemplate, write some code that is fired on the itemdatabound event and programatically change the css class using FindControl.

I know which I would rather use...

Comment: Actually i worry as it does not make sense to me to see the same block just with a different css-class. There should be a simpler way which can be handeld only by editind the mark-up... Shouldn't it?

Comment: In your scenario, it is just a simple CSS change. In others, it may well be a lot different with additional controls, text and css. As said, you are implementing this as intended even if it does seem like a lot of the information is duplicated.

Comment: @pencilCake Using `AlternatingTemplate` can be a quick recipe for disaster as you show, esp when templates gets larger and still mostly equal. It's a strong violation of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). One common solution is to use a wrapper control (then you only have to repeat the declaration), another is to `ItemIndex` in the code-behind. Both have their merits, both avoid dangerous traps like this one.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that the proposed solutions are not satisfying and that there are no other ".net" solution, I would suggest that you do that in javascript (as it doesn't exist in pure CSS).

jQuery allows you to apply a different style on even and odds elements of the selector.
It should work with other elements than table rows...

So something like this should work :

```
$("#rptCommentHistory span:even").addClass("itemTemplate");
$("#rptCommentHistory span:odd").addClass("alternatingTtemTemplate");
```

Or you can just set `ItemTemplate` to all elements and use (it may perform better) :

```
$("#rptCommentHistory span:odd").removeClass("ItemTemplate").addClass("alternatingTtemTemplate");
```